# Probability distribution function symmetrical about origin

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X$ be random variable and it is continuously distributed with $f(-x)=f(x)$ then find $F(0)$ and show
$$P(-a<X<a)=2F(a)-1$$

Comment: Please check your question.

Comment: P(-a<x<a)=2F(a)-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at a symmetric distribution like the normal distribution. The random variable X is distributed as $X\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$

In the picture below $F(a)$ represents the areas $1,2$ and $3$. Area $4$ can be calculated with the converse probability: $1-F(a)$. This area is equal to area $1$. If we substract area $1$ from F(a) we get the area from $-a$ to $a$.

$$P(-a<x<a)=F(a)-(1-F(a))=F(a)-1+F(a)=2F(a)-1$$

[image]

Comment: What's about F(0)?Is it area 1+(2F(a)-1)/2?

Comment: It is just $F(0)=0.5$, since it is the (left) half area of the pdf. But only if the distribution is symmetric around $0$. This is the case here because $f(-x)=f(x)$